# Android: How to get the ID of a parent View?

Tags: android

`View.getRoot()` returns `View`, so we can easily figure out which is the root view by using `getResourceName(View.getId())`.

`View.getParent()`..., while I expect it also returns `View` that is the parent, actually only returns an instance of `ViewParent` that seems to have very very few useful method/fields. It sucks.

So, is there any way to know the ID of the parent? I believe a `View`'s parent is also `View`, thus it should has mID field.

I really wonder why Google didn't let `View.getParent()` just returns `View`. It makes sense, only when something else other than `View` could be the parent, and as far as I know, it's limited to `View` and its subclasses.

Comment: View.getId() return  name of View and View.getClass().getName() retun name of View type

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ViewParent` is just an interface that any View that can have children implements. Most of the times the class you get back will be an instance of a `ViewGroup`, like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "name" but if you want to get the class name you can do so like always: `view.getParent().getClass().getName()`.

Comment: If you want to get the ID, you need to cast it to a `ViewGroup` first. Note that it's not 100% safe because it can also be a `ViewRootImpl`, though I doubt you'll get that in practice. So `((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).getId()`

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) state that the parent is not necessarily a `View`:

> public final ViewParent getParent ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Gets the parent of this view. Note that the
>   parent is a ViewParent and not necessarily a View.
>
> Returns Parent of this view.

However all implementations of [`ViewParent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html) inherit from `View`. This should be a design decision to decouple the parent from a `View` using the `ViewParent` interface, although all implementations in the SDK are views.

Answer (score 3):

Try casting it first. For example, if the parent of the View that you're trying to get id of is a TableRow, then do

```
((TableRow)View.getParent()).getID()
```